# Problem with @Transactional annotation in delete method

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I have code in service layer:

```
@Override
public void removeById(Long id) {
    violationService.removeByCarId(id);
    repository.deleteById(id);
}
```

That's works fine. All remove operations completed success. But problem of this code: thats not transacted. For example of error:

```
@Override
public void removeById(Long id) {
    // remove all violations
    violationService.removeByCarId(id);
    // something wrong in runtime, for example:
    if (2 > 0) throw RuntimeException("123");
    // car was'nt removed
    repository.deleteById(id);
}
```

But when i tried to add `@Transactional` annotation like that:

```
@Transactional
@Override
public void removeById(Long id) {
    violationService.removeByCarId(id);
    repository.deleteById(id);
}
```

Thats crash with error:

```
ERROR: NULL value in column "car_id" of relation "violations" violates NOT NULL constraint
```

I know what means this error, but that's worked without `@Transactional` annotation.
Please, help me to transact method

Comment: I believe something reorders deletes, try calling `JpaRepository#flush` after `violationService.removeByCarId(id)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fixed by adding `flush()` method in `ViolationService.removeByCarId`.